# PHP Syntax error. unexpected $EOF when adding a Wordpress function

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I'm getting syntax error, unexpected $EOF when adding this function to a Wordpress functions file.  See anything?

```
function get_saturation($atts) {
 <?php    $sws = exec("awk -F\",\" '{if(NR==2) printf(\"\%.1f \\n\",($10/8.4)*100 )}'  https://website.org/data/lastrec.csv", $retval);
      echo   $sws . " percent saturation<br>";    ?>
}
add_shortcode('saturation', 'get_saturation');
```

Comment: What's with the `<?` and `?>`?

Comment: Hi, there's actually a separate stack exchange just for word press.

Comment: This isn't a WP specific issue, it's a more "typo" one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have opening and closing PHP tags in the wrong places (within the function, i.e. before `$sws`)

```
 function get_saturation($atts) {
  $sws = exec("awk -F\",\" '{if(NR==2) printf(\"\%.1f \\n\",($10/8.4)*100 )}'  https://website.org/data/lastrec.csv", $retval);
  echo   $sws . " percent saturation<br>"; 
}
add_shortcode('saturation', 'get_saturation');
```

Comment: Yes, that's it and obvious now that you point it out. Thanks!

Comment: Correction: shortcodes should not echo anything, they expect a string to be returned.

Comment: Agreed but that wasn't the question though. The question was a specific error, not ignoring the docs.